# Calculating Extremely Large Powers of 2

Tags: java, primes

I have made a program in Java that calculates powers of two, but it seems very inefficient. For smaller powers (2^4000, say), it does it in less than a second. However, I am looking at calculating 2^43112609, which is one greater than the largest known prime number. With over 12 million digits, it will take a very long time to run. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Power
{
 private static byte x = 2;
 private static int y = 43112609;
 private static byte[] a = {x};
 private static byte[] b = {1};
 private static byte[] product;
 private static int size = 2;
 private static int prev = 1;
 private static int count = 0;
 private static int delay = 0;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  File f = new File("number.txt");
  FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
  for (int z = 0; z < y; z++)
  {
   product = new byte[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
    {
     product[i+j] += (byte) (a[i] * b[j]);
     checkPlaceValue(i + j);
    }
   }
   b = product;
   for (int i = product.length - 1; i > product.length - 2; i--)
   {
    if (product[i] != 0)
    {
     size++;
     if (delay >= 500) 
     {
      delay = 0;
      System.out.print(".");
     }
     delay++;
    }
   }
  }
  String str = "";
  for (int i = (product[product.length-1] == 0) ? 
   product.length - 2 : product.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
   System.out.print(product[i]);
   str += product[i];
  }
  output.write(str.getBytes());
  output.flush();
  output.close();
  System.out.println();
 }

 public static void checkPlaceValue(int placeValue)
 {
  if (product[placeValue] > 9)
  {
   byte remainder = (byte) (product[placeValue] / 10);
   product[placeValue] -= 10 * remainder;
   product[placeValue + 1] += remainder;
   checkPlaceValue(placeValue + 1);
  }
 }  
}
```

This isn't for a school project or anything; just for the fun of it. Any help as to how to make this more efficient would be appreciated! Thanks!

Kyle

P.S. I failed to mention that the output should be in base-10, not binary.

Comment: binary representation is very easy: 1000...00 :) you not just want to compute 2^N but print as decimal, right?

Comment: good task from Project Euler :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key here is to notice that:

```
2^2 = 4
2^4 = (2^2)*(2^2)
2^8 = (2^4)*(2^4)
2^16 = (2^8)*(2^8)
2^32 = (2^16)*(2^16)
2^64 = (2^32)*(2^32)
2^128 = (2^64)*(2^64)
... and in total of 25 steps ...
2^33554432 = (2^16777216)*(16777216)
```

Then since:

```
2^43112609 = (2^33554432) * (2^9558177)
```

you can find the remaining `(2^9558177)` using the same method, and since `(2^9558177 = 2^8388608 * 2^1169569)`, you can find `2^1169569` using the same method, and since `(2^1169569 = 2^1048576 * 2^120993)`, you can find `2^120993` using the same method, and so on...

**EDIT: previously there was a mistake in this section, now it's fixed:**

Also, further simplification and optimization by noticing that:

```
2^43112609 = 2^(0b10100100011101100010100001)
2^43112609 = 
      (2^(1*33554432))
    * (2^(0*16777216))
    * (2^(1*8388608))
    * (2^(0*4194304))
    * (2^(0*2097152))
    * (2^(1*1048576))
    * (2^(0*524288))
    * (2^(0*262144))
    * (2^(0*131072))
    * (2^(1*65536))
    * (2^(1*32768))
    * (2^(1*16384))
    * (2^(0*8192))
    * (2^(1*4096))
    * (2^(1*2048))
    * (2^(0*1024))
    * (2^(0*512))
    * (2^(0*256))
    * (2^(1*128))
    * (2^(0*64))
    * (2^(1*32))
    * (2^(0*16))
    * (2^(0*8))
    * (2^(0*4))
    * (2^(0*2))
    * (2^(1*1))
```

*Also note that `2^(0*n) = 2^0 = 1`*

Using this algorithm, you can calculate the table of `2^1`, `2^2`, `2^4`, `2^8`, `2^16` ... `2^33554432` in 25 multiplications. Then you can convert `43112609` into its binary representation, and easily find `2^43112609` using less than 25 multiplications. In total, you need to use less than 50 multiplications to find any `2^n` where `n` is between 0 and 67108864.

Comment: but what will be the size of operands in those "25 additions" and "25 multiplications"?

Comment: it would be really cool to produce algorithm that will emit digits either one by one or in small groups.

Comment: @Andrey: the multiplications will be enormous, but it's still a huge saving compared to the naive method of doing 43112609 multiplications. However, I guess the number of digits will be less than 43112609 digits (in base-10), since 2^43112609 takes 43112609 digits in base-2 and base-10 always takes less digits.

Comment: @meriton: yep, I made a mistake, they're fixed now though.

Comment: @Lie Ryan well, multiplication with such operands will take ages, so it will not be very efficient. But i think your idea is much better then original one. about digits estimation there is rule `2^10 ~ 10^3`

Comment: @Andrey: The number 2^43112609 will be exactly 12978189 digits in base-10 (because `log(2^43112609, 2) / log(10, 2)` == `43112609 / log(10,2)` == `12978188.500`) which takes about 12MB if 1 digit == 1 byte.

Comment: @Lie Ryan we can pack 2 decimal digits into 1 byte :)

Comment: @Andrey: 12MB is still quite small, you can pack that easily in RAM; multiplying two 12MB numbers using an efficient implementation of long multiplication algorithm will take about 60 MB of RAM, and will produce a 24MB numbers (doable, though it will probably take forever). The OP might also be interested in other multiplications algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm

Comment: I really like this idea. I'll try implementing it tonight. I should've thought about this beforehand. But that's what you guys are for! :)

Answer (score 20):

Displaying it in binary is easy and fast - as quickly as you can write to disk!  100000...... :D

Comment: answer is funny, but precisely correct! author didn't mention what radix does he want.

Comment: actually in hex and octal it is not hard also.

Comment: Haha, I did not mention in my original post that I wanted the output to be decimal. But yes, that's very clever (and true)!

Answer (score 6):

Let n = 43112609.

**Assumption:** You want to print 2^n in *decimal*.

While filling a bit vector than represents 2^n in binary is trivial, converting that number to decimal notation will take a while. For instance, the implementation of java.math.BigInteger.toString takes O(n^2) operations. And that's probably why

```
BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(43112609).toString()
```

still hasn't terminated after an hour of execution time ...

Let's start with an asymptotic analysis of your algorithm. Your outer loop will execute n  times. For each iteration, you'll do another O(n^2) operations. That is, your algorithm is O(n^3), so poor scalability is expected.

You can reduce this to O(n^2 log n) by making use of

x^64 = x^(2*2*2*2*2*2) = ((((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2

(which requires only 8 multiplications) rather than the 64 multiplications of

x^64 = x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x

(Generalizing to arbitrary exponents is left as exercise for you. Hint: Write the exponent as binary number - or look at Lie Ryan's answer).

For speeding up multiplication, you might employ the [Karatsuba Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), reducing the overall runtime to O(n^((log 3)/(log 2)) log n).

Comment: if we assume that one operation will take 1 nanosecond then the whole number will be calculated in 516 hours. thats poor.

Comment: If even Karatsuba isn't fast enough, try Schönhage–Strassen algorithm: `In practice the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm starts to outperform older methods such as Karatsuba and Toom–Cook multiplication for numbers beyond 2^(2^15) to 2^(2^17) (10,000 to 40,000 decimal digits).[4][5][6]` (from Wikipedia). OP's number is about 2^(2^25).

Comment: Andrey, just how did you come up with that number? What value are you assuming for the constant hidden by the O-Notation? And how come you give the same time estimate for my algorithm as for an O(n^2) one?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, powers of two correspond to binary digits.  Binary is base 2, so each digit is double the value of the previous one.

For example:

```
    1 = 2^0 = b1
    2 = 2^1 = b10
    4 = 2^2 = b100
    8 = 2^3 = b1000
    ...
```

Binary is base 2 (that's why it's called "base 2", 2 is the the base of the exponents), so each digit is double the value of the previous one.  The shift operator ('<<' in most languages) is used to shift each binary digit to the left, each shift being equivalent to a multiply by two.

For example:

```
1 << 6 = 2^6 = 64
```

Being such a simple binary operation, most processors can do this extremely quickly for numbers which can fit in a register (8 - 64 bits, depending on the processor).  Doing it with larger numbers requires some type of abstraction (Bignum for example), but it still should be an extremely quick operation.  Nevertheless, doing it to 43112609 bits will take a little work.

To give you a little context, 2 << 4311260 (missing the last digit) is 1297181 digits long.  Make sure you have enough RAM to handle the output number, if you don't your computer will be swapping to disk, which will cripple your execution speed.

Since the program is so simple, also consider switching to a language which compiles directly into assembly, such as C.

In truth, generating the value is trivial (we already know the answer, a one followed by 43112609 zeros).  It will take quite a bit longer to convert it into decimal.

Comment: yup left-shifting 1 n times gives 2^n, and this is very easy and fast to do in C. you could always convert the final output into decimal of course, no need to display it in binary.

Comment: Do remember though that an integer in C is much too small to fit the value you'll be creating, so you'll need some sort of abstraction on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

As @John SMith suggests, you can try. 2^4000

```
    System.out.println(new BigInteger("1").shiftLeft(4000));
```

EDIT: Turning a binary into a decimal is an O(n^2) problem.  When you double then number of bits you double the length of each operation and you double the number of digits produced.

```
2^100,000 takes 0.166 s
2^1000,000 takes 11.7 s
2^10,000,000 should take 1200 seconds.
```

NOTE: The time taken is entriely in the toString(), not the shiftLeft which takes < 1 ms even for 10 million.

Comment: ... did you try that with 43112609? I did, and the statement failed to complete within an hour ...

Comment: if we assume that one operation will take 1 nanosecond then the whole number will be calculated in 516 hours. thats poor.

Comment: Yes, I tried BigInteger, and it also took way too long on my computer.

Comment: The problem is that printing a decimal is an O(N^2) operation.  As you double the number of bits, you double the number of digits produced, however you also double the length of each operation.

Answer (score 0):

The other key to notice is that your CPU is much faster at multiplying ints and longs than you are by doing long multiplication in Java.  Get that number split up into long (64-byte) chunks, and multiply and carry the chunks instead of individual digits.  Coupled with the previous answer (using squaring instead of sequential multiplication of 2) will probably speed it up by a factor of 100x or more.

**Edit**

I attempted to write a chunking and squaring method and it runs slightly slower than BigInteger (13.5 seconds vs 11.5 seconds to calculate 2^524288).  After doing some timings and experiments, the fastest method seems to be repeated squaring with the BigInteger class:

```
    public static String pow3(int n) {
    BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger("2");
    while (n > 1) {
        bigint = bigint.pow(2);
        n /= 2;
    }
    return bigint.toString();
}
```

- Some timing results for power of 2 exponents (2^(2^n) for some n)
- 131072 - 0.83 seconds
- 262144 - 3.02 seconds
- 524288 - 11.75 seconds
- 1048576 - 49.66 seconds

At this rate of growth, it would take approximately 77 hours to calculate 2^33554432, let alone the time storing and adding all the powers together to make the final result of 2^43112609.

**Edit 2**

Actually, for really large exponents, the BigInteger.ShiftLeft method is the fastest.  I estimate that for 2^33554432 with ShiftLeft, it would take approximately 28-30 hours.  Wonder how fast a C or Assembly version would take...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java's BigInteger implementation, but although I don't doubt that it will be able to calculate 2^33554432 with ShiftLefts quickly, I doubt that it can *convert it to decimal* within your 28-30 hours estimation. As has been said previously, calculating the binary representation (or base-32 representation in case of BigInteger) is trivial, it's the binary->decimal conversion that takes time.

Comment: I did those timings based on calculating those powers of two and converting them .toString() and printing them out, which gives the decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

Because one actually wants all the digits of the result (unlike, e.g. RSA, where one is only interested in the residue mod a number that's much smaller than the numbers we have here) I think the best approach is probably to extract nine decimal digits at once using long division implemented using multiplication.  Start with residue equal zero, and apply the following to each 32 bits in turn (MSB first)

```
  residue = (residue SHL 32)+data
  result = 0

  temp = (residue >> 30)
  temp += (temp*316718722) >> 32
  result += temp;
  residue -= temp * 1000000000;

  while (residue >= 1000000000) /* I don't think this loop ever runs more than twice */
  {
    result ++;
    residue -= 1000000000;
  }
```

Then store the result in the 32 bits just read, and loop through each lower word.  The residue after the last step will be the nine bottom decimal digits of the result.  Since the computation of a power of two in binary will be quick and easy, I think dividing out to convert to decimal may be the best approach.

BTW, this computes 2^640000 in about 15 seconds in vb.net, so 2^43112609 should be about five hours to compute all 12,978,188 digits.

Comment: I'm having some trouble figuring out how this works. If it can finish in five hours though, I'd say that is a vast improvement from my code.

Comment: Basically, the sequence is "shift next "digit" into remainder; remainder div 1E9 is next "digit" of the result; remainder mod 1E9 is remainder going into next step.  Like what one would do with pencil and paper, except base-one-billion rather than base-ten.  The other stuff is hard-coded optimization for div/mod one billion.  It computes an approximation and tweaks it until it's exact.  The approximation could probably be improved, but it's pretty good.

Comment: Overall, the goal is simply to pull off digits by repeatedly saying: next_digit is bignumber mod 1E9; bignumber = bignumber div 1E9.  So each pass yields nine decimal digits.